# Setup Google analytics for a website without domain extension

Tags: google-analytics, tracking

I have a share point website running on a server, and have a asp.net website that that is configured to run attached to the share point site. This this not exposed as a domain site( i.e. with .com or .in or .nl etc), i access this site in my development and test environment using a URL something like

**https://www-dev-myname.domainname.local/**

In google analytic i am not able to add this as default URL for an account, it does not allow me to save it.

Is there a way i can create a account with a URL of this type and setup analytic for my site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply enter a valid url - it does not need to be that actual url of your website, the only consequence is that you cannot user inpage analyses (that and the little icon in the page content report that allows you to launch a url in a new window).

Wrong domain name nonwithstanding Google Analytics will work on any domain where it can set a cookie (and if it can't you can set the cookie domain to none, in that case you need to provide a client id yourself to maintain session tracking).

Comment: Hey Eike, I'm digging up this old answer. does that mean as long as I enter a valid URL when adding data stream, and add `gtag.js` script provided to pages I want to track traffic on, it would work?